# Unable to redirect from plugin

Tags: magento2

I am trying to redirect from plugin file but seems no response. Anyone can help?

app/code/Myvendor/ReviewCheck/Plugin/ReviewModel.php

```
<?php

 namespace Myvendor\ReviewCheck\Plugin;

 use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManagerInterface;

 use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

 class ReviewModel {

protected $messageManager;

protected $request;

protected $redirectFactory;

public function __construct(
    MessageManagerInterface  $messageManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
)
{
    $this->messageManager=$messageManager;
    $this->request=$request;
    $this->redirectFactory=$redirectFactory;

}

public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post $subject) {

    $nickNameChecker = $this->request->getPostValue("nickname");

    if(strpos($nickNameChecker,"-")){

        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Nickname cant has dash'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $resultRedirect = $this->redirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/');
        return $resultRedirect;

    }
    else {
        return $this;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your "before" plugin will run and then the normal function will run. This will essentially wipe out your $resultRedirect.

Try doing an aroundExecute plugin instead, executing the parent command when necessary, and injecting your redirect on your use case.